# error facing while returning an array in try block

Tags: java, arrays, string, return, try-catch

how to return a String array when we initilaize the array in try block 
.I face the error that  heading cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public  String[] first()
{    
 try
 {   int value=10;
     String[] heading = new String[10];
     for(int i=0 ; i<value ;i++)
     {
         heading[i] ="";
     }

 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {

 }
 return heading;
```

Comment: Declare it before the `try` block so it's in scope outside of the `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

Move the declaration before
try block

```
public String[] first() {
    String[] heading = new String[10];

    try {
        int value = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            heading[i] = "";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        return heading;
```

With your approach scope of array is limited to try block and you cant access them outside.
Also it is not a good practice to leave catch empty

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the array outside from the try block, there is no need to declare the array in the try block.

Just declare the array outside of the try block so that the scope of the array remains -

```
int value=10;
String[] heading = new String[10];
try{
   for(int i=0 ; i<value ;i++)
   {
     heading[i] ="";
   }
}catch(Exception ex){

}
return heading;
```